# No module named 'redis._compat' ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, kubernetes

As a part of my application to be deployed on kubernetes I have "from rediscluster import RedisCluster" as a part of my code. When I run it on Ubuntu 20.04 with python 3.8.10 I get "No module named 'redis._compat'" error. But I tested it on widows with python 3.8 and it's OK, Please help.

```js
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 from rediscluster import RedisCluster

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rediscluster/__init__.py:7, in <module>
      4 import logging
      6 # rediscluster imports
----> 7 from rediscluster.client import RedisCluster
      8 from rediscluster.connection import (
      9     ClusterBlockingConnectionPool,
     10     ClusterConnection,
     11     ClusterConnectionPool,
     12 )
     13 from rediscluster.exceptions import (
     14     RedisClusterException,
     15     RedisClusterError,
   (...)
     23     MasterDownError,
     24 )

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rediscluster/client.py:12, in <module>
      9 import time
     11 # rediscluster imports
---> 12 from .connection import (
     13     ClusterConnection,
     14     ClusterConnectionPool,
     15     ClusterReadOnlyConnectionPool,
     16     ClusterWithReadReplicasConnectionPool,
     17     SSLClusterConnection,
     18 )
     19 from .exceptions import (
     20     AskError,
     21     ClusterDownError,
   (...)
     26     TryAgainError,
     27 )
     28 from .pubsub import ClusterPubSub

File ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rediscluster/connection.py:22, in <module>
     15 from .exceptions import (
     16     RedisClusterException, AskError, MovedError,
     17     TryAgainError, ClusterDownError, ClusterCrossSlotError,
     18     MasterDownError, SlotNotCoveredError,
     19 )
     21 # 3rd party imports
---> 22 from redis._compat import nativestr, LifoQueue, Full, Empty
     23 from redis.client import dict_merge
     24 from redis.connection import ConnectionPool, Connection, DefaultParser, SSLConnection, UnixDomainSocketConnection

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'redis._compat'
```